# How to assign all the documents in my Mongodb collection to a variable

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to declare my mongodb collections as variables, however when I try to log them the array comes out as empty, the collection is definitely full as I have checked on the mongodb shell. This is an example of one of the collections I'm trying to declare.

```
if (Pizza.length === 0) {Pizza.insertMany(defaultpizzasCollectionItems, function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log("Pizzas saved!");
    }
  })
Pizza.find({}, function(err, pizzas){
let foundPizzas = pizzas;
})
let foundPizzas = [];
console.log(foundPizzas);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `let foundPizzas = Pizza.find({}).toArray()`

Comment: not working unfortunately

Comment: What means "not working"?

Comment: that the solution didn't solve the problem